# Mongodb query using python

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, key-value

I have **key-value pairs** stored in  **MongoDB collections** in the following format.

```
collection 1:
{ entertainment, 22
  popcorn,14
}

collection 2:
{ entertainment, 11
  movie, 16
}
```

How do i query from python to MongoDB in such a way to find the collection with the **highest value/frequency** of a **key ("entertainment" in this case)**?

Expected output: collection 1

Answer (score 0):

On mongo shell, i would do it like below, using pymongo driver this can be replicated easily.

```
db.getCollection('mydummycoll').aggregate([{$sort:{valueToSort:-1}},{$limit:1}])
```